# Embedding HTML page into Chrome Packaged App

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am making a chrome app (and i'm new to it)
and I have made an app but since it's hard to upload stuff to my website I was going to make my app use an html file instead.  so I put in my html file and zipped it, but when I open the app I just get a blank screen.

my code is below, please tell me if I did something wrong.

```
{
"name": "witherers ccg",
"description": "A card trading game",
"version": "1.2",
"manifest_version": 2,
"icons": {
},
"icons": {
"16": "icon16.png",
"128": "icon128.png"

},
"app": {
"launch": {
"local_path": "wither.html"
}
}
}
```

Comment: This looks like a legacy packaged app. You should be designing a Chrome App instead. https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using static pages to serve up your HTML page or app.

Read this page on external content **specifically** see **static pages**: http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external.html

I believe you're running into a CSP issue and inspecting the background page of your app should reveal what's going wrong with simply attaching an html page (or app) as a background page to a Chrome Packaged App.

FYI Static pages are not subject to CSP constraints so you don't need to worry about problems you may be encountering such as eval or external script errors... which is why you might be facing the the white page of death.